# demystify and paint me!

Tags: mathematics, algorithm

To demystify me, look and say.
Then paint me not with colors but with array.

```
11131b4d1c
11121015211514
11121015211514
11121015211514
11121015211514
111318193d1c
111019101534
111019101534
111019101534
111019101534
111019101534
111319113d1c
```

I am a 7-digit number. Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> 1575699

Explanation:

> First, run-length decode the string (the first digit in each character pair is the number of repetitions, the second one is the character to be repeated, e.g. `233d` -> `33ddd`). Then some hexadecimal numbers are obtained. Convert them to binary and get the following:
> `10011101111011101110111011100`
> `10010000001010001000101010100`
> `10010000001010001000101010100`
> `10010000001010001000101010100`
> `10010000001010001000101010100`
> `10011100010011101110111011100`
> `10000100100000101010001000100`
> `10000100100000101010001000100`
> `10000100100000101010001000100`
> `10000100100000101010001000100`
> `10000100100000101010001000100`
> `10011100100011101110111011100`

Comment: Nice! I was afraid it wasn't a well-formed puzzle. Thanks for playing along! =)